# Deleting projects from Dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-es

I can't figure out how to delete dialogflow cx projects. I was messing around with it, and maxed out the number of projects, and now regular dialogflow is broken. There are no agents in any of the projects, but I can't delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow CX project refers to a GCP project as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/setup#project). In order to have multiple agents it is often more useful to create different agents within the same GCP project, as the GCP Console of the project is used to manage GCP-specific Dialogflow CX settings, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/console).

In the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/troubleshooting-project-deletion) you will find the troubleshooting steps to follow if you are having troubles deleting a GCP project.

Considering that your issue seems to have affected the Dialogflow Essentials edition you may need to open a ticket with Support to provide further insights on that matter. However, Bear in mind that Dialogflow CX product is still on its Beta release and the Support that may receive might be limited or it may change in the future.

In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/getting-support) you will find a summary on how to get support for Dialogflow. In case you do not have a paid support plan with Google Cloud Platform it's advised to file the [Dialogflow support form](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/form).

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the prj in https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYU8Q.png)

**After you shutdown the prj, Google will deleted it after 30 days.**